# MacDonalds Hook content formula derivation

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions, symmetric-polynomials

I was trying to understand the derivation of

$$
s_{\lambda}=a_{\lambda+\delta} / a_{\delta}=q^{n(\lambda)} \prod_{x \in \lambda} \frac{1-q^{n+c(x)}}{1-q^{h(x)}}
$$

as given in ([https://math.berkeley.edu/~corteel/MATH249/macdonald.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ecorteel/MATH249/macdonald.pdf)) Page 44, where $b(\lambda)=n(\lambda)= \sum (i-1)\lambda_i$. Here, $s_\lambda$ is the Schur function.

The hook length $h(x)= \lambda_i+\lambda^{\prime}_j-i-j+1$, where $\lambda_i$ is the length of row $i$ and $\lambda^{\prime}_j$ is the length of column $j$. c(x) is the content which is equal $j-i$

I properly understood till the point they reached

$$
\begin{aligned}
a_{\lambda+\delta} =\prod_{i<j} q^{\lambda_j+n-j} \left(1-q^{\lambda_{i}-\lambda_{j}-i+j}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$

After this, I am unable to see how

$$
\frac{q^{n(\lambda)+n(n-1)(n-2) / 6} \prod_{i>1} \varphi_{\lambda_{i}+n-i}(q)}{\prod_{x \in \lambda}\left(1-q^{h(x)}\right)}
$$

is obtained, where $\varphi_{r}(q)=(1-q) \ldots\left(1-q^{r}\right)$. Even after this, how do we arrive at the formula.

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Please include page numbers.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Thanks for the suggestion, done.